# routerLinkActive matching routes with different query parameters

Tags: angular, angularjs-routing

This code generates a handful of links like

/reports

/reports?collection=foo

/reports?collection=bar

All the links are shown as active.  How can I show only the one exact link as active?

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  <a [routerLink]="['/reports']">
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-expand'></span> Reports
  </a>
</li>
<li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" *ngFor="let collection of collections">
  <a [routerLink]="['/reports']" [queryParams]="{collection: collection}">
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'></span><span>{{collection}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query and optional parameters are not included when specifying the route configuration and when matching routes. That's why exact: true is not working for you.

If you need to ensure the routes are treated differently, try using required parameters instead. Then the specifics of the routes are defined in the configuration and considered when the router matches routes.